# JQuery ERB template not inserting HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery, erb

I'm a beginner at JQuery/JS and am trying to implement a dependent drop-down list in a Rails 3.1 app. I have the following form:

```
<%= debug params %>
<%= form_for([@wall.climbing_centre, @wall]) do |f| %>
  <% if @wall.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation"> 
      <h2><%= pluralize(@wall.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this wall from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @wall.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>


  <div id="kind" class="field">
    <%= f.label :kind %><br />
    <%= f.select :kind, Wall::Kinds, :input_html => {:rel => "/kinds"} %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :wall_number %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :number%>
  </div>
 <div id="gradelist" class="field">
    <%= f.label :grade  %><br />
    <%= f.select :grade, Wall::BGrades %>
  </div> 

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The Following JavaScript

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
 'beforeSend': function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript") }
});
jQuery(function($) {
  // when the #kind field changes
  $("#kind").change(function() {
    // make a POST call and replace the content
    $.post('/kinds', {id: $("#wall_kind").val()}, null, "script");
    return false;
  });

})
```

The following JS.ERB template:

```
$("#gradelist").html("<%= label :gbabe, 'Grade'%></br><%=select_tag :gbabe, options_for_select(@grades) %>");
```

The following action in my walls controller:
    def grades_by_kind

```
  if params[:id].present?

    @grades = (params[:id] == "Boulder" ? Wall::BGrades : Wall::FGrades)

  else
    @grades = []
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

I have the following constants in the wall model:

```
FGrades = %w[5 5+ 6A 6A+ 6B 6B+ 6C 6C+ 7A 7A+ 7B 7B+ 8A 8A+ 8B 8B+ 9A 9A+]
BGrades = %w[V0 V0+ V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 15]
Kinds = ['Boulder', 'Leading', 'Top Rope']
```

Changing a selection in the :kind select box, triggers the JS post request, and receives the following response:

```
$("#wall_grade").html("<label for="gbabe_Grade">Grade</label></br><select id="gbabe" name="gbabe"><option value="5">5</option>
<option value="5+">5+</option>
<option value="6A">6A</option>
etc...
<option value="8B+">8B+</option>
<option value="9A">9A</option>
<option value="9A+">9A+</option></select>");
```

However, the drop down values in the id="gradelist" div presented in the webpage aren't actually changing. Why isn't the HTML being changed?

Answer (score 0):

Your select isn't changing because you're not doing anything with the response you're getting from the server. You need to specify a [callback](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) in your `$.post` call. Also, you need to convert your grades to an html option list before returning them, perhaps with `options_for_select`

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for the help. I am using Options for select. The following is my js.erb template: $("#gradelist").html("<%= label :gbabe, 'Grade'%><%=select_tag :gbabe, options_for_select(@grades) %>");. What's strange is that if I use the following code:$("#gradelist").html("blablabla");, the inner html does indeed get replaced with "blablabla".